# Is there a convenient way to have different logging for dev vs prod in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat9

I want my tomcat web app to use one logging configuration file during development, but a different logging configuration file for deployment.

Is there any way to accomplish this? If I put a logging.properties file in the root of my class loader for deployment, that seems to take priority over everything else, so I don’t see a way to add a runtime jvm flag or anything like that to override the configuration during development.

Comment: try java command `-D` options or env vars; they usually have highest precedence

Comment: That's what I thought, but it appears that the -D option is lower precedence than the existence of a logging.properties file in the WEB-INF/classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-D` command-line option in Tomcat. Create two properties file for development and deployment.

Add something like this in development let say log.properites

```
# Development logging configuration 
logging.level.root=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.log=DEBUG  
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.http.impl.connector.ClassLoader=DEBUG          
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.log=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.log=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.connector.ClassLoader=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.connector.ClassLoader=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.core.Controller=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.core.Controller=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.connector=DEBUG 
logging.level.org.apache.catalina.core.Controller=DEBUG
```

In deployment log.properties add

```
properties # Deployment logging configuration 
logging.level.root=ERROR
```

Now use `-D` command-line option

`java -Dlogging.config=logging.properties -jar mywar.war`

What will happen internally is `-Dlogging.config=log.properties` option overrides the development logging configuration in the `log.properties` file, and the application will use the deployment logging configuration in the `log.properties` file.

note : I have tested in my system.

Comment: For this to work, you'd need to avoid putting a logging.properties file in the WEB-INF/classes folder, right? For deployment, I want to include a logging.properties file in the deployed .war file.